# How get all numerical values from a list except numbers relating to certain Strings

Tags: list, groovy

I want to get all the numbers from my String except for the numbers that are related to the String pattern 'SPN'

```
 def layoutStr = '1 ABC, 2 DEF, 3 SPN, 4 GHI'

 def splitted = layoutStr.split(',')
   *.trim()                        // remove white space from all the entries (note *)
   *.dropWhile { it ==~ /[^0-9 ]/ } // drop until you hit a char that isn't a letter or a space in the list
   .findAll { it[0] != 'SPN' }     // if a group starts with SPN, drop it

assert splitted == [1, 2, 4]
```

This doesn't seem to do what I expect it to do, I think I am missing the re-collecting step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `findResults` which only collects elements that aren't null, so you can use it to filter AND transform at the same time:

```
def layoutStr = '1 ABC, 2 DEF, 3 SPN, 4 GHI'

def splitted = layoutStr.split(',')
    *.trim()        // remove white space from all the entries (note *)
    *.split(/\s+/)  // Split all the entries on whitespace
    .findResults { it[1] == 'SPN' ? null : it[0] as Integer }

assert splitted == [1, 2, 4]
```